# Use variable as role name in function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can't use variable as role name

I tried to create function with trigger on insert, witch perform some grant statements for given id's. I declared some variable with id value and have to use it as role name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permissions() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $permissions$
    DECLARE
        id varchar  := NEW."id"; --this variable will contain user name ex. "valid.user"
    BEGIN
        GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA zakupy TO id;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$permissions$;

CREATE TRIGGER permissions_insert AFTER INSERT ON public.permissions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE permissions();
```

When I add new row i have error message  ERROR:  role "id" does not exist.
If I replace id to "valid.user":

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA zakupy TO "valid.user"
```

statement works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permissions() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $permissions$
DECLARE
    id varchar  := NEW."id"; --this variable will contain user name ex. "valid.user"
BEGIN
    execute 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA zakupy TO "'||id||'"';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$permissions$;
```

Comment: Works perfektly. Thank you.